# Checking whether mailbox is empty? in erlang

Tags: erlang

I need to do a check, which returns true or false, depending on whether the current process has any message in its mailbox in erlang.

Comment: The broader problem is to find the last message in the process's mailbox.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the `process_info/2` BIF to access process information including the message queue. So

```
process_info(self(), message_queue_len) => {message_queue_len,Length}
```

and

```
process_info(self(), messages) => {messages,MessageList}
```

The second one is inefficient if there are many messages in the queue as the list is created for each call (though not the messages of course). There are many interesting things you can find out about a process. There are no restrictions on which process you can get info, you can do it for any process.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use `0` for the `receive` timeout. In the example below, it will try to get a message out of the queue, if there are none in there it will return the atom `false`.

```
1> receive _ -> true  
1> after 0 ->
1> false
1> end.
empty
```

Be warning this **will** consume a message.

One other way would be to use `erlang:process_info` but this is supposedly only for debugging.

```
6> {message_queue_len, QueueLen} = erlang:process_info(self(), message_queue_len).
{message_queue_len,0}
7> QueueLen.
0
```

Altogether now:

```
16> HasMessages = fun(Pid) ->                                           
16>     element(2, erlang:process_info(Pid, message_queue_len)) > 0     
16> end.
#Fun<erl_eval.6.80247286>
17> HasMessages(self()).                                                                      
false
18> self() ! test.
test
19> HasMessages(self()).
true
```

Comment: Sorry, but your answer is wrong. Your code wastes one message and so disrupt the correctness of any computation.

Comment: Also, there's a warning that it will consume the message.

Comment: Sorry, I know that they are two answers, what I'm saying is that despite your warning, that function (the first one) is still not acceptable because it wastes a message. Please point out a use case in which this function doesn't disrupt normal message flow and has no side effects on process message queue. About the second answer, it's a correct one so I'm simply advising you to remove the first one.

Comment: Also for the first answer, you can always resend the message to yourself, if message order is not important.
`receive M -> self() ! M, true after 0 -> false end.`

Comment: +1 for Aronisstav. But still, I don't this is an acceptable solution. I still prefer the process_info way

Comment: This still could disrupt correctness, because it changes the order messages are delivered (you take the first message and put it into the end).

Answer (score 1):

Internally there are means to test if there is a message in the process mailbox.

But beware! I don't think Erlang is meant to be used like that:

```
{module, hasMsg}.
{exports, [{module_info,0},{module_info,1},{hasMsg,0},{peekMsg,1},{lastMsg,1}]}.
{attributes, []}.
{labels, 17}.

{function, hasMsg, 0, 2}.
    {label,1}.
        {func_info,{atom,hasMsg},{atom,hasMsg},0}.
    {label,2}.
        {loop_rec,{f,4},{x,0}}.
        {move,{atom,true},{x,0}}.
        return.
    {label,3}.
        {loop_rec_end,{f,2}}.
    {label,4}.
        timeout.
        {move,{atom,false},{x,0}}.
        return.

{function, peekMsg, 1, 6}.
    {label,5}.
        {func_info,{atom,hasMsg},{atom,peekMsg},1}.
    {label,6}.
        {loop_rec,{f,8},{x,0}}.
        return.
    {label,7}.
        {loop_rec_end,{f,6}}.
    {label,8}.
        timeout.
        return.

{function, lastMsg, 1, 10}.
    {label,9}.
        {func_info,{atom,hasMsg},{atom,lastMsg},1}.
    {label,10}.
        {loop_rec,{f,12},{x,0}}.
        {test,is_eq_exact,{f,11},[]}.
    {label,11}.
        {loop_rec_end,{f,10}}.
    {label,12}.
        timeout.
        return.

{function, module_info, 0, 14}.
    {label,13}.
        {func_info,{atom,hasMsg},{atom,module_info},0}.
    {label,14}.
        {move,{atom,hasMsg},{x,0}}.
        {call_ext_only,1,{extfunc,erlang,get_module_info,1}}.

{function, module_info, 1, 16}.
    {label,15}.
        {func_info,{atom,hasMsg},{atom,module_info},1}.
    {label,16}.
        {move,{x,0},{x,1}}.
        {move,{atom,hasMsg},{x,0}}.
        {call_ext_only,2,{extfunc,erlang,get_module_info,2}}.
```

Compile: `erlc +from_asm hasMsg.S`.

The module `hasMsg` contains:

- `hasMsg/0` returns a boolean  whether there are messages in the mailbox.
- `peekMsg/1` returns the oldest message without removing it. Returns its argument, if the mailbox is empty.
- `lastMsg/1` returns the newest message without removing it. Returns its argument, if the mailbox is empty.

Comment: I would not do it this way unless you have suicidal tendencies and love assembler hacking. These instructions are not defined and there are no guarantees they will remain. I give a slightly cleaner way below.

Comment: @rvirding, I would never use such code. I only wanted to see if it was possible. Hacking to the limit. ;) I'd say one's algorithm is utterly broken, if one has to peek the newest or oldest message in the mailbox …